# Is it possible to create a fluid simulation of rain?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Is it possible to simulate rain with the fluid simulator?

I tried to do something with a bunch of *Inflow* cubes that get enabled and disabled, however this is *very* tedious. Is there a better way?

---

*I realize that using a fluid simulation is probably overkill, I'm attempting this as a test. I should also note that I only want this for the simulation of the impact of the droplets on a hard surface, so I only need to simulate ~50 or so droplets*.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend this, even if you have tons of ram. Particles and dynamic paint are a much better alternative.

Comment: WOW. Why do you want fluid for rain ? Is it for testing purpose ? Instead you can use "fluid" type of particle's physics...

Comment: The main reason is because I want to have it collide with a mesh and run down the sides etc. (The whole thing is a test)

Comment: @gandalf3 Particles can collide, you could probably fake the rest with dynamic paint and animated droplets etc.. not sure if Blender supports wetmaps either?

Comment: @iKlsR Well, I know they can collide, but I mean collide with realistic splashing, splattering and spraying? I am trying this a test anyway, so I'm not really looking for the most efficient way to do it (though that would be good to know too..)

Comment: [BlenderGuru](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-create-realistic-rain/) has done a tutorial on realistic rain, particle system for rain and dynamic paint for it hitting the road. One thing that we still don't have since 2.50 is reactor particles [see 3rd particle system here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Physics/Particles/Fireworks), maybe dust off 2.49 to get splash particles on impact.

Comment: @sambler What about collisions with something else, e.g. a car? As for 2.49, I don't suppose there's a way to convert the particles afterwards so I can render in cycles? (for stills I could probably just convert it, but I don't know, I've never used 2.49 before :P)

Comment: Here's a tutorial that's a couple of years old. It's not based on a fluid simulator (it uses a particle system and dynamic paint), but it might be worth watching. http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-create-realistic-rain/

Comment: @bill_080 Thanks :) (Though [sambler already linked to that video](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/is-it-possible-to-create-a-fluid-simulation-of-rain?noredirect=1#comment7755_4925)) I'm looking for a way to simulate the collision and splashing against a hard convex surface. (I should note that I'm not planning to make as large a simulation as that, I just want to make some detailed drips on a mesh.)

Comment: @gandalf3 - Oops, I didn't read the comments, so I didn't realize that tutorial was already linked.   I noticed that my answer has already been deleted and replaced as a comment here.

Comment: @gandalf3 you can setup kill on collision to any object, to trigger the reactor particles. I'm sure we could make particles real back then, but it would still be one frame.

Comment: @sambler One frame is a start, I don't necessarily need it to be animated. I'm just not sure how to create something like [this image found with google](http://www.earthonlinemedia.com/ebooks/tpe_3e/mass_movement_weathering/rain_splash_NRCS_p0000003256_small.jpg) with particles.

Comment: @gandalf3 for that particular image I would have a fluid sim with an object falling into it. That is a pool of fluid with something landing in it, not a drop of water exploding on impact.

Comment: @sambler Well, anyway what I wanted was that kind of detail, be it water hitting an object or an object hitting water. I just wanted to know if there is an easy way to simulate rain drops in the fluid simulator. I only need a few high-detail drops for close ups, the rest can be particles.

Comment: Create your drop object with softbody or something else... Add a modfier called "Particle Instance" and point this to the Particle System that will simulate the rain

Answer (score 5):

You can try the *Fluid* physics type in a particle emitter :

- Add a particle system to a plane and configure it the way you want (number, start, max age...)
- In the *Physics* panel, select *Fluid*.
- Select the object you want the particles to run down on
- Add a *Collision* physics modifier to this object (make sure it has enough faces), with *particle damping Factor* set to `1`
- hit play and:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next, you just have to create a nice shader (this one is a blueish transparent shader, just for demonstration, very bad)

However, this type of simulation is not very realistic and some tweaks may be needed to suit your needs. It's just a track...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I take it there is no way to mesh these into a single solid object instead of a lot of spheres?

Comment: This would be great, indeed... But I don't know how. Metaball instance for particles, maybe ?

Comment: Protip: metaball instance for particles (if you can get it to work; I've done it in the past but it's tricky and unpredictable) is an *excellent* way to melt your CPU. Once you start getting into the hundreds it'll take a long time to orbit the scene, much less render.

Comment: Lowering the metaball resolution on the instanced meta will help